# Python isn't finding Tensorflow or Keras in RStudio

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, keras

I'm using RStudio on Windows 10 (on a Dell XPS 15 2018) and I'm trying to use Keras with Tensorflow backend, never having installed Python/Anaconda/Miniconda before.

I've been running into problems the entire way :(. I tried this a week ago but I couldn't do it so I deleted everything and I'm starting over now, but I'm still facing issues.

First I installed Miniconda into `C:/mini`, and then I installed the `keras` and `tensorflow` packages using standard installation. I downloaded Python and 3.8 and the `dll` file too.

I run the following:

```
library(keras)
library(tensorflow)
library(reticulate)

use_python("C:\\Users\\NK\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps", required=T)
Sys.setenv(RETICULATE_MINICONDA_PATH = "C:/mini")
```

and it works, but then I run:

`mnist <- dataset_mnist()`

and I get

```
Error: Python module tensorflow.keras was not found.

Detected Python configuration:

python:         C:/Users/NK/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python.exe
libpython:      C:/Users/NK/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python38.dll
pythonhome:     C:/Program Files/WindowsApps/PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1217.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0
version:        3.8.4rc1 (tags/v3.8.4rc1:6c38841, Jun 30 2020, 15:17:30) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:           [NOT FOUND]
tensorflow:     [NOT FOUND]

NOTE: Python version was forced by use_python function
```

My Tensorflow package is installed in `C:\Users\NK\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\tensorflow`, and my Keras package in `C:\Users\NK\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\tensorflow`.

I run `> reticulate::miniconda_path()` and get `[1] "C:/mini"`, which is correct.

Here is some troubleshooting output:

```
> reticulate::py_discover_config()
python:         C:/Users/NK/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python.exe
libpython:      C:/Users/NK/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python38.dll
pythonhome:     C:/Program Files/WindowsApps/PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1217.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0
version:        3.8.4rc1 (tags/v3.8.4rc1:6c38841, Jun 30 2020, 15:17:30) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:           [NOT FOUND]

NOTE: Python version was forced by use_python function
```

I've looked at *every* GitHub and Overflow post describing similar issues, but for some reason my installation just isn't working. I just want to be able to use Keras :(. Please help

Comment: Did you create an environment in conda? If not you should start by doing that. Recently I installed `keras` from scratch and I think the main steps are the following: 1) create conda environment, 2) install rstudio inside that environment, 3) run rstudio in the environment, 4) set rstudio to use conda environment, 5) install keras package.

Comment: I already have RStudio on my computer -- do I have to uninstall and reinstall it into the environment? Thank you :)

Comment: I think you just need to install another Rstudio inside the conda environment (you can leave the other Rstudio installed). You should be able to see the Rstudio of that environment in your Start programs like Rstudio (name_of_environment). Use that RStudio to do the steps I mentioned previously.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem when installing keras for tensorflow v2.2 in Python 3.8.5. At that point I was doing an install with only tensorflow and keras with it. I installed keras separately using pip and importing directly from keras and that fixed my issue.

Comment: Please add more details regarding the steps you should do to fix this problem